# AWS EB and Symfony : How to launch bin/console command during deploy, wrong directory

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install a symfony app on AWS EB. And I need to launch a bin/console during the deploy and I failed at it.

Here ma .config file.

```
commands:
  10updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.3.2  
  20updateDB:
    command: php bin/console d:s:u -f
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root  
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /web
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: composer_options
    value: --optimize-autoloader
```

And my command `20updateDB` does not work my command are not launched from the app directory but from `/`

Here the response

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Could not open input file: bin/console.
```

Did you know where is stored the app during the deployment process ?

Comment: Try the absolute path to the `console` file

Comment: I don't know it. I haven't found clear info about what is really happening during the deploy command. I will be glad if someone could give me a link which explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you should not use `commands` but `container_commands` which is run after but inside the container so `bin/console` will be accessible.

Also the environment variable are only available in `container_commands`.